# Matplotlib - graphs are stacked on each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to visualize two Seaborn boxplots using the fig (ax) method as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


sns.set_palette('colorblind')
sns.set_style('white')



prd_data = pd.read_csv("Products 20171001-20200825.csv", sep=';', decimal=',')
prd_data['Product'].replace('Prd', 'Product ', regex=True, inplace=True)
prd_data_ess = prd_data.loc[prd_data['Base Type'] == 'ESS']
prd_data_premium = prd_data.loc[prd_data['Base Type'] == 'PRM']


fig, (ax0,ax1) = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(12,6), sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax0 = sns.boxplot(y='Product', x='Update Minutes', data=prd_data_ess, orient='h', \
                 order=['Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3', 'Product 4'], \
                 boxprops=dict(alpha=0.3), color='#05BDC7')

ax0.set_xlim(0)
ax0.set_title('Products ESS - Update Minutes')
ax0.set(xlabel='')
ax0.set(ylabel='')
ax0.plot()

ax1 = sns.boxplot(y='Product', x='Update Minutes', data=prd_data_premium, orient='h', \
                  order=['Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3', 'Product 4'], \
                  boxprops=dict(alpha=0.3), color='#E63322')

ax1.set_xlim(0)
ax1.set_title('Products PRM - Update Minutes')
ax1.set(xlabel='')
ax1.set(ylabel='')
ax1.plot()
plt.show
```

But I end up with a visual that ax0 is blank, and the data for both ax0 and ax1 printed on ax1, making the second visual garbled, like this:

[image: top values printed on the bottom chart]

Can you please give me a hand on what might be causing the issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Johan, That solved it! Thanks very much for your help! Can you please post your reply as an answer? It looks like you added it as a comment and I am not able to upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `ax0 = sns.boxplot(...)` you need `sns.boxplot(...., ax=ax0)` and similarly for the second plot: `sns.boxplot(...., ax=ax1)`.

By default, seaborn uses the ["current ax"](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#working-with-multiple-figures-and-axes) for the plot. You can draw on another `ax` by providing the `ax=` parameter. Seaborn also returns the `ax` it used, which then can be used to change the plot (tick settings, labels, ...). Note that when no explicit `ax` is given, multiple seaborn functions in succession will use the same `ax`.

Also note that some seaborn functions can create a [complete grid of subplots](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html), and return a `FacetGrid` object instead of an `ax`.